# How reduce duplication between create/edit forms?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, breeze, durandal

I am using C#, Breeze and Durandal to create an SPA but this question relates to more than SPA's. Often times you have entities that you want to create and also edit. Take this simple entity:

```
class Entity {
   [Key]
   public int Id;
   [Required]
   public String FirstName;
   [Required]
   public String LastName;
}
```

Now you need to create a create and an edit form for this entity (* 100 other entities). The simple way is to create two forms one for each function. However, these forms will be almost exact duplicates.

If no fields were required you when someone clicks "Create" you could create the entity in the db and redirect them to /edit/$id. However you want to use the automatic validation generated by the annotations for users who Save edits.

What is a good way to reduce duplication of the form html and backend code? Simply having two view models sharing the same view might be good enough but I am not sure how to do that with durandal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No fields are required until you Save the entity by committing it.  You can create an entirely empty entity even if there are fields marked required on the server.  Simple use manager.createEntity('Entity'); and then show your editor view to input the first and last name and then call save.  No different than in ASP.Net MVC showing a view and testing ModelState before saving.

Your statement about validation holds true whether you are creating or editing the entity for all intents and purposes, if there is something special you are doing show a snippet and I can try to help further.

Comment: Thanks, yes this makes sense. That is what I ended up doing.